# Unable to mock CognitoIdentityServiceProvider functions from aws-sdk in jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Aws.config.js

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.update({
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_REGION,
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_IDENTITY_POOL_ID
    })
  });

const AwsCognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18' });

export default AwsCognitoIdentityServiceProvider;
```

I have a function in **ListUser.js**

```
import AwsCognitoIdentityServiceProvider from 'components/aws/AwsConfig';

const userList = () =>{
 
    var params = {
        UserPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_USERPOOL_ID,
        AttributesToGet: null,
        Filter:""
    };
    AwsCognitoIdentityServiceProvider.listUsers(params,function (err, data) {
        if(data) {
                //fetching data here successfully
        } else {
            console.log("error",err);
        }           
     })
   }
```

My test file ListUser.test.js

```
const mockListUsers = jest.fn((params) => {
  return {
    promise() {
      return Promise.resolve('mock response');
    }
  };
});


jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  return {
    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider: jest.fn(() => ({
      listUsers: mockListUsers
    })),
    config: {
      update: jest.fn()
    }
  };
});

describe('ListUser', () => {
  
    test('renders ListUser component', () => {
      act(() => {
        render(<ListUser />);
      });
    });
});
```

I am not able to mock this function and return response I am getting error below:

```
  TypeError: _AwsConfig.default.listUsers is not a function

      90 |         Filter:""
      91 |     };
    > 92 |     AwsCognitoIdentityServiceProvider.listUsers(params,function (err, data) {
```

I have also tried with keeping aws.sdk.js file inside *mocks* folder but no luck

```
_mocks_/aws.sdk.js

class AWS {
    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = class {

        listUsers = jest.fn(() =>{
         return { promise: ()=> Promise.resolve({mockresponse})}
      });
    };
  }
  
  module.exports = AWS;
```

I need to mock listUsers function but not able to do so. I have followed so many links but no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
jest.mock('aws-sdk');
    
AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.prototype.listUsers = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      promise: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({})
    });
```

Comment: I have tried with this my test case is passing but with no coverage. I think it is not coming inside listUsers function. Response is not coming what I have mocked.

Comment: This worked for me though. I will update you later

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way and worked for me.

```js
jest.mock("aws-sdk", () => {
  const cognito = { listUsers: jest.fn() };
  return {
    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider: jest.fn(() => cognito),
    config: {
      update: jest.fn(),
    },
  };
});
const mCognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
mCognitoIdentityServiceProvider.listUsers.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
  return {
    promise() {
      return Promise.resolve('your mock data');
    },
  };
});
```